# Unity WebGL Application Making Calles to AWS S3 Bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, unity-game-engine, security, amazon-s3, unity-webgl

I’m trying to create a Unity WebGL application that can pull images and stream video securely from an S3 bucket.
I see that WebGL isn’t supported by the Unity AWS SDK and when I try I’m getting the same errors as the guy in this thread: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=248490

I’m trying to find a workaround to this but I’m no web developer so all this is very new to me. If someone could point me in the right direction to a workaround that may be feasible it would be very helpful.

The guy in the above forum post mentions using the JavaScript SDK. Is it possible to use the JavaScript SDK in a unity project?
Another thought was to use the HTTP Get to interact with Cognito first to acquire verification before images are pulled from the bucket?